# jQuery(window).load(function() {}) executed after images are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, wordpress

I have a problem. Inside a generated by PHP file I have a jQuery gallery plugin which should make `display:none` to all the images which were placed in correct order by PHP in `div`s. But apparently, when I run, I first see images loading from the page, and then JavaScript gallery run and hides images and show them in correct way.

I would like to run my script before browser would try to load images from `div`s on the page. I keep them in separate `div`s so that it's SEO friendly and if JavaScript is turned off they will be shown all together on one page.

The body is something like:

```
<div>
    <img> ...  </img>
</div>
...       
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
         ....myCode...
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want to start with initial default classes to avoid a 'Flash Of Unstyled Content' (sometimes referred to as FOUC).

However, you'll be in better shape if you use the `jQuery(document).ready(function(){})` call instead of `$(window).load(fn)`.  Document.ready is fired before the images load, while window.load doesn't occur until those images have loaded.

Comment: so would you suggest  making all images visible: hidden and so that i don't see them, but it's still SEO friendly? But then again if JS is turned off, there will be nothing shown.  p/s/ I will try with (document).ready function now.